# Check folder path and write output to a file

Tags: powershell

I have to have complete a task testing over 10,000 paths.

I want to check if a folder path exist and write the output to a file.

```
Test-Path \\servername\folder | Out-File C:\temp\test-path.txt
```

The file contains true but I would like it to output the file like this

```
\\servername\folder  true
```

or

```
\\servername\folder false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python, if the project does not specify whether to use PS or not

You can check if a path exists with `try` and `open()`

Code:

```
k = [listofyourpaths]
j = ''
l = []
with open(output file) as file:
  for i in k:
    try:
      j = open(i)
      j.close()
    except:
      
      file.write(i+' false')
    else:
      file.write(i+' true')
file.close()
```

Comment: I have to use powershell

Comment: Okay then, I don't have much experience with PowerShell so I think I wouldn't have a good answer, but I will give it a try